# Stuck on Jech's Set Theory Exercise 2.3

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

From Jech's *Set Theory*:

> ***Exercise (2.3)***. If $X$ is inductive, then $X\cap\text{Ord}$ is inductive. $\textbf{N}$ is the least nonzero limit ordinal, where $\textbf{N} = \bigcap\{X:X\text{ is inductive}\}$.

I'm struggling to prove the second statement; specifically that $\textbf{N}$ is transitive (already know it is a woset), which is needed to show it is an ordinal.

I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: You can prove that if $X$ is inductive then $\{x\in X \mid x\subseteq X\}$ is also inductive.

Comment: See Exercise 1.3.